# PDO Error In SignUp Class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm working on my own SignUp class but it seems I have a problem with the PDO calls
The browser returns this to me:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

I have my database configuration in a file included then on the main page. It's as follows:

```
   <?
   $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=magazin-online;host=localhost;';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';

   try{
       $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
   }catch(PDOException $e){
       echo 'Connection failed!: '.$e->getMessage();
   }
```

An the line in the SignUp class causing the error is this:

```
   $pdo->query("insert into ... () ... values ());
```

Now, I don't make any db connection in my SignUp class because I already included the file resposible for it.

How can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using `exec` instead of `query`:

```
$pdo->exec("insert into ... () ... values ());
```

Answer (score -1):

You are catching the exception generated by the new PDO, and then continue execution.

By doing it this way, you have to check that the class exists, so change:

```
if( $pdo) 
  $pdo->query("insert into ... () ... values ());
```

But .. a better way is not to continue execution after a critical error like this.
So better change the connection like this:

```
   $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=magazin-online;host=localhost;';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';

   try{
       $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
   }catch(PDOException $e){
       echo 'Connection failed!: '.$e->getMessage();
       die;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, $pdo is a global variable. If you are calling $pdo->query inside a function, you either have to pass the $pdo connection as a parameter or declare it as global

```
global $pdo;
```

in the beginning of the member function.